# Error when trying to get value of an entity attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I'm trying to get value from entity attribute:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.mapaView setDelegate:self];


    MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = self.loja.endereco; // <-- Here
    request.region = self.mapaView.region;

    MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        NSMutableArray *placemarks = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems) {
            [placemarks addObject:item.placemark];
        }
        [self.mapaView removeAnnotations:[self.mapaView annotations]];
        [self.mapaView showAnnotations:placemarks animated:NO];
    }];
}
```

But I get this error:

```
2015-08-03 21:01:41.196 MinhaBrasilia[2465:69970] -[__NSCFDictionary endereco]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb2faed1910
2015-08-03 21:01:41.199 MinhaBrasilia[2465:69970] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary endereco]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb2faed1910'
```

Loja (self.loja) is an entity, which was created from a plist, filtered using NSPredicate, loaded by method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` and passed as parameter via `prepareForSegue:sender`, all in the previous screen.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     LojaTableViewCell *celula = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:IdentificadorCelula
                                                                forIndexPath:indexPath];

     self.listaFiltrada = [self carregarPlistDeLojasComId:identificadorBtn filtradaPor:self.txtCategoria];

     self.loja = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Loja" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

     [self.loja setValue:[[self.listaFiltrada objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"titulo"] forKey:@"titulo"];
     [self.loja setValue:[[self.listaFiltrada objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"subtitulo"] forKey:@"subtitulo"];
     [self.loja setValue:nil forKey:@"categoria"]; //Not implemented
     [self.loja setValue:[[self.listaFiltrada objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"endereco"] forKey:@"endereco"];
     [self.loja setValue:nil forKey:@"quadra"]; //Not implemented
     [self.loja setValue:[[self.listaFiltrada objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  objectForKey:@"telefone"] forKey:@"telefone"];


     [celula preencherCelulaComTitulo:self.loja.titulo
                         comSubtitulo:self.loja.subtitulo
                         comCategoria:self.loja.categoria
                          comEndereco:self.loja.endereco
                            comQuadra:self.loja.quadra
                          comTelefone:self.loja.telefone];

    [celula setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
     return celula;
 }

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    self.loja = [self.listaFiltrada objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SegueLoja sender:self.loja];
}

#pragma mark - Segue
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:SegueLoja]) {
        DetalheViewController *detalheVC = (DetalheViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
        [detalheVC setLoja:sender];
    }
}
```

Apparently I'm getting a dictionary, in which, if I do `request.naturalLanguageQuery = [self.loja valueForKey:@"endereco"];` I can get the attribute I want, but this way I believe that I am not using the resources of CoreData.

Comment: `endereco` looks like a key for a `NSDictionary`... did you try using `request.naturalLanguageQuery = self.loja[@"endereco"];`? Or... `request.naturalLanguageQuery = [self.loja objectForKey:@"endereco"];`?

Comment: Still I had not tried that way. I thought doing `self.entity.attribute` would work, considering that the entity is charged and the attributes were filled. Even that way `[self.entity valueForKey: @ "attribute"];` is the "right way" to use the CoreData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because `self.loja` is a dictionary: in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you have:

```
self.loja = [self.listaFiltrada objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

which is an NSDictionary derived from your filtered plist, NOT the `NSManagedObject` that you create in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  The dictionary does not implement the `endereco` method, hence the error.  It does implement `valueForKey`, so that will work: but if you follow this route, you are accessing the key of a dictionary, not the NSManagedObject.

I think you should rethink your approach - using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to process the plist into `NSManagedObject`s is a bad idea.  It will only be called for visible cells, and will potentially be called several times for the same row (if it is scrolled on and off screen).  I would write a routine to process all the plist into Core Data, and produce an array of `NSManagedObject`s that you can then use as the data source for the table view.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly I was thinking about my usage of CoreData, but I doesn't know how to implement. You say create an method to read the plist and return NSManagedObject. So in method cellForRowAtIndexPath get this method that return NSManagedObject as data to populate cells.

Comment: Reading your plist and converting it to CoreData will be permanent; it's a once-only operation (unless the plist changes?).  So you could add a method to your App Delegate to do it.  Then in `viewDidLoad` of your table view, you could fetch all the NSManagedObjects into an array (you could include a predicate to filter them to match `txtCategoria`).  Then you use that array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  Or you could use `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch the objects.

Comment: The plist file will not change. Can I create my own method or need put conversion in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method? By doing this, when I fetch the `NSManagedObjects` to an array I will not fall on the same concept that I am currently using, right?

Comment: I would add your own method to load the plist into CoreData, and call it from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.  Then in your table view controller, you do not need to refer to the plist at all; you can just fetch the NSManagedObjects - which should avoid the specific error you are getting but also provide a robust data source for the table view.